# Selenium Webdriver | DragAndDrop Feature | No Exception, but code is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I'm trying to drag and drop and logo to an container, not getting exception. I'm able to find elements and the same drag and drop code is working fine for another site with other elements. But don't know why this is not working here. Can any one assist.

```
// Searching elements 

    driver.get(https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?ilename=tryhtml5_draganddrop");
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("iframeResult")));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.id("drag1"));
    WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.id("div1"));

//Drag and Drop Action

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action DragnDrop = builder.clickAndHold(From).moveToElement(To).release(To).build();
    DragnDrop.perform();
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on this site. I tried different approaches with drag and drops, Actions interface, finding element via javascript, switching to default content between, before, after drag & drop - nothing worked. Sorry, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience to achieve more stable drag and drop actions we switched from Actions implementation to a javascript one. Yes, it might look like a hack, but constant false negatives of test result made us measure the risk and use the js impl. (We didn't create the script from scratch, just applied multiple suggestions found in the internet)

You can use it for your case, add the code below instead of Actions you used.

```
driver.executeScript("function dnd(elemDrag, elemDrop) {\n" +
                        "    var DELAY_INTERVAL_MS = 100;\n" +
                        "    var MAX_TRIES = 10;\n" +
                        "    var dragStartEvent;\n" +
                        "    if (!elemDrag || !elemDrop) {\n" +
                        "        return false;\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "    function fireMouseEvent(type, elem, dataTransfer) {\n" +
                        "        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');\n" +
                        "        evt.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, elem);\n" +
                        "        if (/^dr/i.test(type)) {\n" +
                        "            evt.dataTransfer = dataTransfer || createNewDataTransfer();\n" +
                        "        }\n" +
                        "        elem.dispatchEvent(evt);\n" +
                        "        return evt;\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "    function createNewDataTransfer() {\n" +
                        "        var data = {};\n" +
                        "        return {\n" +
                        "            clearData: function (key) {\n" +
                        "                if (key === undefined) {\n" +
                        "                    data = {};\n" +
                        "                } else {\n" +
                        "                    delete data[key];\n" +
                        "                }\n" +
                        "            },\n" +
                        "            getData: function (key) {\n" +
                        "                return data[key];\n" +
                        "            },\n" +
                        "            setData: function (key, value) {\n" +
                        "                data[key] = value;\n" +
                        "            },\n" +
                        "            setDragImage: function () {\n" +
                        "            },\n" +
                        "            dropEffect: 'none',\n" +
                        "            files: [],\n" +
                        "            items: [],\n" +
                        "            types: []\n" +
                        "        }\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "    fireMouseEvent('mousedown', elemDrag);\n" +
                        "    dragStartEvent = fireMouseEvent('dragstart', elemDrag);\n" +
                        "    function dragover() {\n" +
                        "        fireMouseEvent('dragover', elemDrop, dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "    function drop() {\n" +
                        "        fireMouseEvent('drop', elemDrop, dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n" +
                        "        fireMouseEvent('mouseup', elemDrop);\n" +
                        "        fireMouseEvent('dragend', elemDrag);\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "    setTimeout(dragover, DELAY_INTERVAL_MS);\n" +
                        "    setTimeout(drop, DELAY_INTERVAL_MS * 2);\n" +
                        "    return true;\n" +
                        "}\n" +
                        "   dnd(arguments[0], arguments[1])", From, To)
```

Source: https://github.com/WileyLabs/teasy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/wiley/utils/JsActions.java

p.s. There is a typo in the link from your question. (instead of "asp?**ilename**" it should be "asp?**filename**)